# I can not access to if statement in c

Tags: c, shell, unix, append, system

I was trying to access the `if` statements for `append`, `in`, and `out` but only the "append" works for now.

I don't know why it does not work for `in` and `out`. Could you please tell me what is the problem?

The `args` contents, if I type "ls > hi.txt," are:

```
    args[0] = ls
    args[1] = >
    args[2] = hi.txt
    args[3] ='\0'
```

```c
for(i = 0; args[i] != (char*)'\0';i++)
{
    if(strcmp(args[i],"<")==0)
    {
            args[i] = NULL;
            printf("IAMHERE\n");
            strcpy(input,args[i+1]);
            in = 2;
    }
    if(strcmp(args[i],">")==0)
    {
            args[i] = NULL;
            printf("IAMHERE\n");
            strcpy(output,args[i+1]);
            out = 2;
    }
    if(strcmp(args[i],">>")==0)
    {
            args[i] = NULL;
            strcpy(output,args[i+1]);
            append = 2;
    }
}
if(append)
{
    printf("yohere\n");
    if((fap = open(output,O_RDWR|O_APPEND))<0)
    {
            perror("Could not open outputfile");
            exit(0);
    }
    dup2(fap,STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(fap);
}
if(in)
{
    printf("yohere\n");
    if((fin = open(input,O_RDONLY,0))<0){
    perror("Couldn't open input file");
    exit(0);
    }
    dup2(fin,0);
    close(fin);
}
if(out)
{
    printf("yohere\n");
    if((fout = creat(output,0644))<0){
            perror("Could not open the outputfile");
            exit(0);
    }
    dup2(fout,STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(fout);
}
```

Comment: Can you show what is `args` and its contents and edit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65979468/edit) plz

Comment: note that bash would consume `>` before your program runs if typed on the command line

Comment: @헬창공돌이 : You did not show how you set your variable `args`, but in any case, if you would really invoke it as `ls > hi.txt,`, only `ls` would be available. The first argument to your program would be the program name itself, and the second argument would be `ls`. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have (potential) undefined behaviour in your `for` loop: the second and third `if` statements should be `else if`, instead (after all, only one of the three possibilities can actually be satisfied).

As it stands, when the *first* `if` block (`if(strcmp(args[i],"<")==0)`) is executed, the code inside that block sets `argv[i]` to a `NULL` pointer, which is then used as the first argument to the `strcmp` in the *second* `if` test. That call to `strcmp` causes undefined behaviour, as `NULL` ***is not*** a pointer to a `nul`-terminated string.

A similar situation occurs when the *second* `if` block is entered: the test in the *third* will then cause undefined behaviour.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp):

> The behavior is undefined if lhs or rhs are not pointers to
> null-terminated byte strings.

---

So, when your operator is `>>` ("append"), the undefined behaviour is not invoked, because neither of the first two `if` blocks is executed; however, with `<` or `>`, one of those *is* entered, `argv[i]` is set to `NULL`, and the UB occurs; that UB *may* include the `strcmp` function 'incorrectly' returning zero, and thus one or both of the other `if` blocks will be executed, causing your program to give incorrect results.